# PHP controllers. Separation of concerns between serving pages and forms

Tags: php, codeigniter, separation-of-concerns

I know there is a lot of debate about which PHP framework is the best and this isn't a thread about this ;). This thread is about how do developers handle the separation of concerns belonging to a controller.

In MVC-ish framework, the controller will serve pages (get) and accept form submission (post). However, I found that even trivial controller can be hard to understand.

With the following CodeIgniter example:

```
 class TrivialController extends MY_CONTROLLER{

         public function login(){
           //Load a view containing a login form
         }

         public function login_p(){
           //Load user model + login
           //Success / Faillure view
         }

    }
```

or

```
class TrivialController extends MY_CONTROLLER{

         public function login(){

              if(GET){
                  //Load a view containing a login form
              } else if (POST) {
                 //Load user model + login
                 //Success / Faillure view
              }

         }
    }
```

I found both option to be equally cumbersome:

- Option 1: Two methods with the same name, for the same feature. It'll make the controller harder to read.
- Option 2: A method driven by a big `if-else` on the request type. It'll make the method harder to read.

So, here's the question. How do you handle this in practice?

Comment: This is a subjective question, unsuitable for SO, possibly suitable to another StackExchange site (programmers, or codereview if you include actual working code). However, generally this is handled by a convention, eg `function getLogin()...function postLogin()` or `function showLogin()...function processLogin()`The switch/if else design is awful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GET/POST are two different, yet functionally cohesive things.

This is a very common workflow in web applications:

- A **GET** request is made, which triggers a query to construct a form
- A **POST** request is made, which is

  - A) Validated and a command is executed. Sequentially, the client is redirected to as success page.
  - B) Failed the validation. Sequentially, the client is redirected to failure page (most likely the **GET** page).

I consider these to be different enough to split the into different methods, but similar enough to keep in the same controller.

The problem is the naming convention. You should concisely distinguish between [command and query](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html) actions, and make use of `object-verb` names that describe the subject what you are working with, and what you are doing with it.

```
class TrivialController extends MY_CONTROLLER{

     public function askCredentials(){
       // Show login form
     }

     public function verifyCredentials(){
       // Login
     }

}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, then CodeIgniter automatically creates the routes based on controller structure, in which case you could consider it an example of [Facade Pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FacadePattern), and push the distinction a level lower.